# Global variable reverts back to default value in Python Luigi Pipeline

Tags: python, luigi

```
var_doesHave = True

    class A:
         global var_doesHave
         var_doesHave = False

         # Call Class B

    class B:
         if (var_doesHave):
              # do foo
         else:
              # do bar
```

I have python luigi pipeline code that looks something like this. When I examined the terminal, it seems that the program calls class A and set doesHave = false, but before it runs Class B, doesHave reverts back to true.

Basically, I want to do 'bar', but it keeps doing 'foo' because the global variable keeps reverting back to true.

Could anyone explain why this is happening? I'm almost certain this has something to do with Luigi Pipeline, not Python itself.

Answer (score 0):

**You're not using python properly**. Inside classes you should use methods, in particular the `__init__` method if you want to run some code when you initialize an instance (ie when you call `A()`) or the `__call__` method if you want to run code when a class gets called.

So fixing your code:

```
var_doesHave = True

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        if (var_doesHave):
            print("foo")
        else:
            print("bar")

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        global var_doesHave
        var_doesHave = False
        B()

A()
```

Also notice that your code isn't properly indented.

Comment: The order of class declarations doesn't matter here - ``B()`` isn't called until ``A()`` is called, which happens after both declarations.